# how to make the progress bar invisible in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

There is a list of pictures made through RecyclerView. When you click on a picture while it is being transferred to the next activity, a ProgressBar should be displayed. When there is a return to the activity of the image selection, the ProgressBar also remains visible, although it must be hidden.

As I did below, the progress bar becomes invisible only in the first image, but in the rest it does not work. I can’t understand why

in my project there are such classes as:

**interface**

```
public interface ImageOnC {
    void onClick(int position);
}
```

**ImageViewHolder**

```
   public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        private ImageOnC imageOnC;
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public void setImageOnC(ImageOnC imageOnC) {
            this.imageOnC = imageOnC;
        }

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_outline);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progr);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imageOnC.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**ImageAdabter**

```
public class ImageAdabter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Integer> listImages;

    public ImageAdabter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listImages = getImages();

    }

    private List<Integer> getImages() {
        List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

        results.add(R.drawable.outline1);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline2);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline3);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline4);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline5);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline6);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline7);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline8);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline9);
        results.add(R.drawable.outline10);

        return  results;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_images,parent,false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource( listImages.get(position));
        holder.setImageOnC(new ImageOnC() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(int position) {
                Common.PICTURE_SELECTED = listImages.get(position);
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, Colorful.class));
            }
        });


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object>payload){
    //if so, then the progress bar only works for the first image in recyclerview
        if(!payload.isEmpty()){
            if(payload.get(position) instanceof Integer)
                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        else super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payload);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listImages.size();
    }
}
```

**I add this to activity**

```
private void initView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_images);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adabter = new ImageAdabter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adabter);
    }
      @Override
        public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          if (adabter != null) {
              adabter.notifyItemChanged(position, position);
          }
      }
```

Comment: try to remove this condition `if(payload.get(position) instanceof Integer)`

Comment: this also works only for the first image. But also a progress bar appears in some images before I click on the image

Answer (score 0):

in xml file use Progress bar visibility gone

Comment: really?))
I did it first